# Is there a way to tell how much the Apollo 11 50th anniversary bumped traffic to the site?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that there was an uptick, but I don't know how to tell.

Comment: I'm interested to see how it compares to the uptick after Elon's red sports car was "sent to Mars", and ideally *to its 50th anniversary* but I don't think I'll be finding that out...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was a nice bump, but it was nothing compared to the bump of the first Falcon Heavy launch. It was comparable to the bump in November of last year, which happened for a reason I can't figure out at the moment. The launch of Falcon Heavy continues to be the time of most activity on this site, including even the private beta. In the last year it had the highest number of answers, and a tie for the highest number of questions asked over a period of time.